# I'm using a custom circular animation by a GitHub repo in my project but it gives some error

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using a circular animation custom segue in my ViewController and it works fine but when I add a new button in by ViewController and link it to another ViewController through simple segue it gives me SIGABRT error. The line in which I get the error is :

"let secondVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController"

of code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let secondVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
    secondVC.transitioningDelegate = self
    secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom

}
```

Comment: Are you really sure that `segue.destination` is a `SecondViewController`?

Comment: Yes it is and it works fine, but when I add another button to my VC and link a simple segue to another VC it shows SIGABRT error in that line.

Comment: You say it works then you say it doesn't work. Which is it? It can't be both working and not working.

Comment: It works when I have no button except the one which creates the Circular Animation, but it gives the error when I add another button.